# I am having trouble with this ajax timer it is not doing what I expect and does not execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I am back to this not executing I have in php head the following  https://deniserose.000webhostapp.com/fetch_sql.php

```
<head>


<title>Audio Stream</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have in java script  which i am loading at end of the php file

```
<script src = 'js/fetch_updater.js'></script>
```

now this never seems to get run

```
// Start Clock refresh

// uses new new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater( 
// in main fetch file to trigger the auto update of the page.
// Written by Denise Rose

var gUpdateDiv="";
var gContentURL="";
var gcheckInterval=0;
var gcheckURL = "";
var gCurrentCheck  ="";





_fetchUpdater('track_data','/fetch_sql.php','/fetch_sql.php',6000);


function _fetchUpdater(updateDiv,contentURL,checkURL,checkInterval)
{
    gUpdateDiv = updateDiv;
    gContentURL = contentURL;
    gcheckInterval = checkInterval;
    gCheckURL = checkURL;
    
    setTimeout('Check();',gcheckInterval);
}

//Called by _fetchUpdater every (n) seconds  determines if content should be updated as page loaded.
function Check()
{
   new Ajax.Request(gCheckURL,{method:'get',  onSuccess:CheckResponse});
   setTimeout('Check();',gcheckInterval);
}



// looks for the response and determines if the div should be updated. 


var openFile = function(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
          var text = reader.result;
          var node = document.getElementById('output');
          node.innerText = text;
          console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};

function CheckResponse(transport)
{
    var content = transport.response.Text;
    var base64file1 = openFile('/images/nowplaying-artwork_2.png');
    var base64file2 =  $('outerimg').$('#np_track_artwork').src.value;
    
    if(base64file1 != base64file2) {
    
    //if(gCurrentCheck != content) {
       
      gCurrentCheck = content;
       
      new Ajax.Request(gContentUrl, {method: 'get',onSuccess:function t() { 
         $(gUpdateDiv).innerHTML = t.responseText; /*t.response.json()*/}
        
        
      });
      
      $time = new Date().getTime();
      new Ajax.Request('outer_img', {method: 'get',onSuccess:function s() { 
         $('outer_img').innerHTML = "<img id='#np_track_artwork' src='/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png?t='"+$time+" alt='Playing track artwork' width='200' height='200'>"}
          
      });
           
    }
    //setTimeout('Check();',gcheckInterval);
}
```

It's supposed to look at an image on the website at images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png and check if its changed as apposed to the one on screen using the JavaScript and ajax calls. I know the one in directory is changing but this never gets activated as far as I can tell  unless you refresh whole page. Using crtl +shift I. There must be something I am doing wrong? But I cannot figure out why it doesn't execute.  Is this something silly like directory locations?

I get this error in MIT Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.7.2

- (c) 2005-2010 Sam Stephenson

Which is **[violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 296299ms prototype.js**

```
  function delay(timeout) {
    var __method = this, args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
    timeout = timeout * 1000;
    return window.setTimeout(function() {
      return __method.apply(__method, args);
    }, timeout);
  }
```

I looked at code inspection. It does  run CheckResponse() it needed to be non inferred unlike SetTimeout() can anyone help as its doesn't get any further it may be my base64 stuff  but need help? Is it possible my read javacode is not working please?

Reporter said it might be use of SetTimeout() but the SetTimout() are called to update the timer when they have cleared so this cannot be the issue and it is still unknown why it doesn't work.

I had some more time today so ran an inspection with Ctrl = Shift+I

I  could see Check Response Firing ok  https://i.gyazo.com/f4f0a3ea8a9fcddd864b420ddadddb21.png. It must therefore not be reading the image properly I used one from this site I am not surprised it didn't work  I did put a post up but no one answered it and provided a working outcome [Obtaining base64_decode($artwork) from a web page <img> in a DIV and file in JavaScript and comparing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541102/obtaining-base64-decodeartwork-from-a-web-page-img-in-a-div-and-file-in-jav)

I have tried several version all do not funcions as the PHP version I had did what I am looking for is:

```
function OpenFileOrig() {

    $r = fopen('images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png', 'wb');
        if ($r !== false) {
             fread($r,base64);
             if (base64) base64 = base64_encode(base64);
    } else fclose($r);
      
    
    
}
```

I have also tried

```
 var openFile = function(file) {
    var input = file.target; 

    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };

const getBlobFromUrl = (myImageUrl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', myImageUrl, true);
        request.responseType = 'blob';
        request.onload = () => {
            resolve(request.response);
        };
        request.onerror = reject;
        request.send();
    });
};
const getDataFromBlob = (myBlob) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(myBlob);
    });
}
const convertUrlToImageData = async (myImageUrl) => {
    try {
        let myBlob = await getBlobFromUrl(myImageUrl);
        console.log(myBlob);
        let myImageData = await getDataFromBlob(myBlob);
        console.log(myImageData);
        return myImageData;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return null;
    }
};
```

Neither seem to function That will run in JavaScript
furthermore it can show how far it gets here https://i.gyazo.com/77c16c54f9cb91e1f1ef8be0d4fc7589.png  why are these read routines on Stack Overflow as answers if they don't work?

Also you can see here that the debugger will only stop in one place https://i.gyazo.com/ade6187a03d5faa53a8c0237680086b4.png even if I use 'Continue to here' by right clicking break point it won't go to the next break point is this an issue with the timers jumping out before the code is executed?

I also ran it through the open image the jpg shows the position it appears not to get url the debugger marks in intalic below as show in picture
https://i.gyazo.com/3e1e74503d4e3676b67606eff0012570.png

```
var openFile = function(file) { *file = "/images/nowplaying_artwork_2"*
```

and

```
 var input = file.target; *input = undefined*
```

and

```
var reader = new FileReader(); *reader = FileReader{readystate:0, result:null, error: null,onloadstart=null,onprogress:null...}*
```

I change the open file to this as it was more readable and got the url in file

```
function openFile(file) {
    var input = file; // file.target removed as not passing url

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```

It still did not read file giving exception

Ok so have been looking again

It gives exception here under catch (e) 'this.dispatchException(e);' in [prototype.js][1]:

```
  respondToReadyState: function(readyState) {
    var state = Ajax.Request.Events[readyState], response = new Ajax.Response(this);

    if (state == 'Complete') {
      try {
        this._complete = true;
        (this.options['on' + response.status]
         || this.options['on' + (this.success() ? 'Success' : 'Failure')]
         || Prototype.emptyFunction)(response, response.headerJSON);
      } catch (e) {
        this.dispatchException(e);
      }
```

When i run  `$r = fopen('/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png', 'wb');`

**Trying**

```
function openFileOrig() {
   var base64; 
   var r;
   try {
       r = fopen('/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png', 'wb');
        if (r !== false) {
             fread(r,base64);
             if (base64) base64 = base64_encode(base64);
        }
      
    } catch (err) {
       if(r) fclose($r);
       console.log(err);
       return null;
    }
    
}
```

So I now get a message when running Perfomance tool that fopen is not defined  at openFileOrig which is much better as it gives better hint, but strange https://www.careerride.com/JScript-read-and-write-file.aspx but a much better answer here the Stack Overflow entries first in google list did not show this https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/399116/Javascript-read-data-froma-txt-file

**So as none of the origanal file commands which was available in JavaScript as of my books JavaScript 1.1 are now available  I went back to original function reader**

```
function openFileOrig2(file) {
   var base64; 
   var r;
   var img_src;
   
   try {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
          img_src = event.target.result;
          // We do something
          if (img_src) base64 = base64_encode(img_src);
        });
        
       reader.addEventListener('progress', (event) => {
       if (event.loaded && event.total) {
          const percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
          console.log(`Progress: ${Math.round(percent)}`);
       }});
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } catch (err) {
    
       console.log(err);
       return null;
    }
}
```

Lets see what this does as expected it gave a blob error

I tried next

```
var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    try {
       var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
          var img_src = reader.result;
          // We do something
          if (img_src) base64 = base64_encode(img_src);

        };
        reader.readAsDataUrl(input.target);
    } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
    }    
};
```

**But  reader.readAsDataUrl is no longer a function according to the error logged in console and this is incorrect information.**

"javascripture.com/FileReader" and misleading I have writen and reported this error and type error: reader.readASDataUrl  to javascripture.com this is not a function  in Chrome browser.

Now its saying input one is not a blob? What is this then:

```
    var FILE = new Blob();
    FILE.target = '/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png';
    FILE.files = FILE.target;
    var base64file1 = openFile(FILE);
```

**I tried again from another example on Stack Overflow question and answers  27251953 but wrapped it in error checker. This also failed 'ReferenceError: blob is not defined'**

Why are all these things on Stack Overflow if the no longer function?

```
    try {
        var file = new File([blob], "/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png",{type:"image/png", lastModified:new Date().getTime()})
    } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
```

**Problem persists with blobs not solvable**
Well it worked on the StackOverflow snippet runner Can I asked why it didn't work on 000WebHostApp the moderator said again ask here . Is this because it requires node.js ? or something else ?

** Update**
I solved my problems with the image update here [Obtaining base64_decode($artwork) from a web page <img> in a DIV and file in JavaScript and comparing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541102/obtaining-base64-decodeartwork-from-a-web-page-img-in-a-div-and-file-in-jav) . However we are left with the text which does not refresh . The only way itsees I could do this was to create the table in another file create_sql_div.php which created just the table . It sees I would have to find a way to update the innerHTML. I am not sure how to get this into the main page from javascript but will post again when I have had some time to look at it. However I did tentively try   document.querySelector('#np_track_text').innerHTML='/create_sql_div.php'; but I dont think its loading the URL into a form it can fill the div with?

I tried

```
function updateTextDisplay() {
   // document.querySelector('#np_track_text').load('/create_sql_div.php');
   //     document.getElementById('#np_track_text').redraw;
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
   client.open('GET','/create_sql_div.php');
   client.onreadystatechange = function() {
       document.querySelector('#np_track_text').innerHTML = client.responseText;
   };
   client.send;
   
}
```

**Hmmm**

I switched to this Ajax call as they had worked before , but still get no error and no html changes

```
function updateTextDisplay() {
   // document.querySelector('#np_track_text').load('/create_sql_div.php');
   //    
   new Ajax.Request('/create_sql_div.php', {method: 'get',onSuccess:function t() { 
         document.querySelector('#np_track_text').innerHTML = t.responseXML;
         document.querySelector('#np_track_text').redraw;
        }
   });
   
}
```

It gives error 'Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input' does anyone know what this means as google is vague This file can be opened in browser with out error so why is this saying this error please?

**Steps to replicate error**
Clearly steps to replicate this error are easy to follow 1) load website deniserose.000webhostapp.com/fetch_sql.php wait at least 6000ms 2) You will see the bottom division  turns to 'Undefined' take copy of source 3)refresh the page it will come back completed take copy of source. 4) Compare both sources using [www.diffchecker.com](http://www.diffchecker.com) this states "The two files are identical" As this is the case what is going wrong here ?

**Ok I have the answer**

finally the references to t.responseText are wrong this should be t.arguments[0].t.responseText ;   and not t.responseXML either . lol I found it in the Google debugger variables so all is good i hope D Hugs

@enhzflep I cant open new question so am adding to this one I  get error using SQL phpMyAdmin

```
create function SPLITSTRING (@String AS VARCHAR(256)) RETURNS VARCHAR(256) AS (
SELECT `genre` LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX(';',@String +';'-1),STUFF(@String,1,CHARINDEX(';',@String + ';','') FROM`played_songs` UNION ALL
SELECT  `genre` LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX(';',@String +';'-1),STUFF(@String,1,CHARINDEX(';',@String + ';','') FROM`played_songs` FROM SPLIT_STRING WHERE @String >'' 
  )                                                             
SELECT `genre` FROM SPLIT_STRING ORDER BY `genre` ASC
```

it reports Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized data type. (near "AS" at position 37) any ideawhy please?

Comment: Are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  When you use the browser's script debugger to step through the code as it executes, what specifically happens?

Comment: `onSuccess:'CheckResponse()'` should probably be `onSuccess:checkResponse` and notice `c` and `C`

Comment: you have `onSuccess:'CheckResponse()'` but your function is `function checkResponse`, also you should just pass the function reference as the value instead of the string, eg `onSuccess:checkResponse}`

Comment: @virtualKitten uhm,  are your sure that you want to use `setTimeout()` instaed of `setInterval()`?

Comment: Nope the first timer checks the page is loaded and reports back when its loaded the second Check Response timer looks at the image on server and on page and compares it  and pushes new image if its not .

Comment: CheckResponse is firing https://i.gyazo.com/f4f0a3ea8a9fcddd864b420ddadddb21.png

Comment: @Reporter  am still not having much luck it seems most of the information on  blob creation no longer works?

Comment: `setTimeout('Check();',gcheckInterval);` seems more that a little bit fishy. You're supposed to pass a function and an interval to `setTimeout`. Instead, you've passed a string that contain a function name, some parenthesis and a semi-colon. I.e `setTimeout(Check, gcheckInterval);` is what I'd expect to be reading.

Comment: @enhzflep No the timers work fine with no problem and never did my problem was in relation to  image base64 code obtaining it comparing it, which seems unlocatable in JavaScript.  . Such as it is  I went a different route to get it working but  get this silly error message  above which I have asked internet company to look at  using  document.querySelector( freezes the issue doing nothing  using document.getElementById reports undefined error as the error comes to the console Uncaught fetch_sql.php Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input on next track song event.

Comment: @virtualKitten - while it may indeed function, it's not doing what you think it is. What you've in fact done, is create an anonymous function, whose body contains the call to Check. Here's an example: `setInterval('console.log("called from anonymous function");', 1000);` - I'm only passing setInterval 2 parameters. Still unconvinced? Compare that to this: `setInterval(console.log, 1000, 'param passed to setInterval callback');` ... Documentation is your friend. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep Good morning to you . I have now put together the information for you  . I spoke to Hostinger yesterday regarding problems inserting SQL from a php file https://deniserose.000webhostapp.com//create_sql_div.php into a html DIV on the first page https://deniserose.000webhostapp.com/fetch_sql.php returning 'undefined' instead of contents of second link. Where I am using a Javascript file https://deniserose.000webhostapp.com/js/fetch_updater.js  Clearly enclosed tag checker and  Diff Checker found no difference post and prior event  something is wrong?

Comment: @enhzflep Clearly steps to replicate this error are easy to follow 
1) load website deniserose.000webhostapp.com/fetch_sql.php  wait at least 6000ms  
2) You will see the bottom division <div id='#np_track_text'> turns to 'Undefined' take copy of source 
3)refresh the page it will come back completed take copy of source. 

4) Compare both sources using www.diffchecker.com this states "The two files are identical" As this is the case what is going wrong here ?

Comment: @virtualKitten - when you get the source as your instructions guide one to, you're not getting a snapshot of the DOM at that instant, but are instead getting a copy of the file that was loaded. It's for this reason I've written code to populate (big) tables after page-load in the past - it results in a smaller download.

I tried to copy and paste the site address you've supplied, but get a 404. When I edit the URL to include https://www - I get a certificate error (the cert is for 000.webhostapp.com - it's not personalized, so the browser is wary. Ignoring it's efforts to 'keep me safe'

Comment: results in a different page - but still not one that I think you're intending. This time, it says  "No such website".. Ohhhhw - I've just seen the edit to your question that appears to indicate you solved the problem. :thumbsup: